# Where can I see whether the kernel is done restarting in JupyterLab?

Tags: jupyter-lab

From time to time I have to restart the kernel in JupyterLab. Where can I see whether the kernel is done restarting in JupyterLab?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an indicator in upper right corner of the tab (gray circle). But to be honest it doesn't show detailed status.

I would recommend trying [JupyterLab Status Bar](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-statusbar) extension. It provides statusbar which will display statuses like idle, reconnecting, starting etc.